# Count number of times a date repeats x times in another sheet within given date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In one sheet I have a set of dates (in column A). Each date entry logs an execution with different variable values:

Sheet 1:

```
05/03/2021
05/03/2021
05/03/2021

05/04/2021
05/04/2021

05/05/2021
05/05/2021
05/05/2021

05/06/2021
05/06/2021

05/07/2021
```

In another sheet, I have 2 named cells: from_date and to_date (for a report range)

Sheet 2:

```
from_date = 05/03/2021
to_date = 05/07/2021
```

In Sheet 2, I want to count all the occurrences where an execution occurs 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. times within the date range.

For example, if an execution occurs 3 times on 4 different dates, the Total Executions would be 12 for 3 Executions Per Day.

Expected Output:

```
| Executions |   Total    |
|   Per Day  | Executions |
|------------|------------|
|      1     |      1     |
|      2     |      4     |
|      3     |      6     |
|      4     |      0     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an interesting question and there are so many ways to do this, so I would be interested in seeing the other answers.

**Method 1** *- probably not the form you want based on your screenshot*

Here is a formula that requires Excel 2019 or Excel 365.  I put the following formula into cell A2 in Worksheet:

```
=LET( xdates, Sheet2!A:A,
       fdates, FILTER( xdates, (xdates >= from_date)*(xdates <= to_date) ),
       udates, UNIQUE( fdates ),
       frq, FREQUENCY( fdates, udates ),
       bins, SORT( UNIQUE( FILTER( frq, frq > 0 ) ) ),
       ffrq, FREQUENCY( frq, bins ),
       IFERROR( INDEX( bins, SEQUENCE( ROWS( bins ) ), {1,2} ), FILTER( ffrq, ffrq > 0 ) ) )
```

Where I put **xdates**, you put in the column that contains your execution dates. This generates a Dynamic Array that has your Executions per Day frequencies in the left column and Total Executions in the right column.

[image: screenshot of outcome]

This formula first filters the dates according to your from and to dates in **fdates**. It then creates a list of unique dates (**udates**) from that filtered outcomes. It then computes the frequency of fdates against udates in **frq** and makes a sorted list of frequencies called **bins**. It then calculates the frequency of the frequencies across these bins in **ffrq**.

It finally assembles the result by creating an index with bins in the left column with a SEQUENCE to dynamically shape the number of rows in the table according to the number of bins `SEQUENCE( ROWS( bins ) )`.  It creates a second column with the array `{1,2}` that will force an error in the second column - this is where IFERROR steps in and replaces the error with `FILTER( ffrq, ffrq > 0 )` which is the ffrq that has been filtered to exclude the final zero frequency row.

**Method 2** *- this looks more like your screenshot*

Here is an alternative - in case you want the Executions Per Day to be an iteration from 1 to the maximum frequency without skipping any frequencies with zero occurences, you could use this instead:

```
=LET( xdates, Sheet2!A:A,
       fdates, FILTER( xdates, (xdates >= from_date)*(xdates <= to_date) ),
       udates, UNIQUE( fdates ),
       frq, FREQUENCY( fdates, udates ),
       mxfrq, MAX( frq ),
       bins, SEQUENCE( mxfrq ),
       ffrq, FREQUENCY( frq, bins ) - ( bins = 1 ),
       IFERROR( INDEX( bins, bins, {1,2} ), INDEX( ffrq, bins ) ) )
```

> NB: I found that this version was adding 1 to the 1 time per day
> counts, so I corrected ffrq by removing that extra count.

[image: iterating from 1 to max number of bins]

**Method 3** *- static executions per day*

This version does not discover the executions per day.  It relies on you putting them into column A (in this example):

```
=LET( xdates, Sheet2!A2:A30,
      xPerDay, A2:A6,
       fdates, FILTER( xdates, (xdates >= from_date)*(xdates <= to_date) ),
       INDEX( FREQUENCY( COUNTIF( xdates, UNIQUE( fdates ) ), xPerDay), xPerDay, ) )
```

This greatly simplifies the formula.  Just as before the execution dates are loaded into **xdates** (Sheet2!A2:A30 in this example). But this also takes in the Executions Per Day array as an input to **xPerDay** (which is A2:A6 in this example).

If you extend Executions Per Day, you need to extend xPerDay.  You could set Executions Per Day to =SEQUENCE( n ) in cell A2 and change xPerDay to A2# and it would let you more easily change the static list of Executions Per Day without editing the formula in B2.

[image: screenshot of static frequencies]

Comment: I have a suspicion that it could be done more simply than this. This tries to automate both sides to make Executions Per Day and Total Executions automatic and responsive to the inputs.  However, if you wanted Executions Per Day to be fixed with Total Executions reading each row, then the formula could be simplified.  Steps were added twice to remove zeros and they would not be needed.  Would be interesting to see alternative approaches.

Comment: I think there is a simpler way to do it. Executions Per Day is static, Total Executions needs to read the rows in another sheet. I was thinking something with a series COUNTIFS, but don't know how to check if a date is repeating multiple times.

Comment: ahh ok- if they are static and don't have to be discovered, the formula is much simpler.  Will post that, but will have to wait until i have a break later today CET.

Comment: OK - so I made a version with static Executions Per Day.  Note: one of the issues is that you cannot nest COUNTIF or COUNTIFS. A way to get around that is to use FREQUENCY with COUNTIFS or to create helper cells. The real reason to put this into a LET is to introduce the date filtering that you wanted.  It would otherwise be possible to do this with `=INDEX( FREQUENCY( COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A2:A30, UNIQUE( Sheet2!A2:A30 ) ), A2:A6 ), A2:A6 )`.